Can we find a vertex maximal path in a bipartite graph?
Let's define vertex maximal path ($\text{vmp}$): suppose a path $P$ is vertex maximal if its vertex set $V(P)$ and any vertices $v$ can't form a longer path, i.e. the set $V(P)\cup \{v\}$ can't form a path longer than $P$.
Now we have a bipartite graph with partite sets are $X$ and $Y$, and I want to know if we can find a $\text{vmp}$ with at least one endpoint in $Y$ if $Y$ has more vertices than $X$.
As a further hypotheses let's suppose that

no isolated vertices because an isolated vertex is a $\text{vmp}$ of length $0$, and
the graph connected.

